# A word for the basic elements of a videogame (physics, rules etc.)

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm looking for a word that describes, in game development, the stage at which you have finished programming the character's physics, the basic rules of the game and possibly the graphics and music.

I'm not talking about an "engine" as that is much more bare bones than the stage I'm talking about, though it's similar. I could use the Unity engine and start making a game, and then get to the point where I have finished programming the rules and the physics and what kind of a game it is, and now all that is left is creating levels and finishing touches.

I suppose "framework" is kind of what I'm looking for, but more specific to videogames.

> I'm using the Unity Engine. I have just finished creating the ******, now all that's left is to create some actual levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time ago when I was taking software engineering classes, we were taught that in-house testing was **alpha**. Once it goes to public or outside-the-studio, it's called beta. That said, I've seen a lot of people throwing those words around willy nilly.

So I would say you have an early alpha game with the game mechanics and assets added.

Answer (score 1):

> **First playable**
>   The first playable is the game version containing representative gameplay and assets, this is the first version with functional major gameplay elements. It is often based on the prototype created in pre-production. Alpha and first playable are sometimes used to refer to a single milestone, however large projects require first playable before feature complete alpha. First playable occurs 12 to 18 months before code release. It is sometimes referred to as the "Pre-Alpha" stage. [Wikipedia - Video game development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_development)